# asp.net 5 & mvc 6 how to use PersianCalendar in dnx core 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

i used this code for get Persian celander  in mvc 6 and when bulid project get 
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'PersianCalendar' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
my code is

```
public static string PersianDate(this DateTime dateTime, bool isShowDay = false)
        {


        var persianCalendar = new PersianCalendar();
        var day = string.Empty;
        if (isShowDay)
            day = Getday(dateTime);
        return
            $"{persianCalendar.GetYear(dateTime):0000}/{persianCalendar.GetMonth(dateTime):00}/{persianCalendar.GetDayOfMonth(dateTime):00} {day}".Trim();
    }

    private static string Getday(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        switch (dateTime.DayOfWeek)
        {
            case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                return "شنبه";
            case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
                return "یکشنبه";
            case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                return "دوشنبه";
            case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
                return "سه شنبه";
            case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
                return "چهارشنبه";
            case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
                return "پنج شنبه";
            case DayOfWeek.Friday:
                return "جمعه";
            default:
                return string.Empty;
        }

    }

    public static string GetFullTime(this DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return $"{dateTime.Hour:00}:{dateTime.Minute:00}:{dateTime.Second:00}";
    }
```

Comment: Is is possible to get a ```CultureInfo``` via ```CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo()``` and use its ```Calendar``` property to access a calendar that happens to be Persian?

Comment: can you add code sample??

Comment: i try this for get CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo() not available in dnx core 5

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line of code, which is related to Calendars package, into the `project.json` file:

```
"dnxcore50": {
      "dependencies": {
        "System.Globalization.Calendars": "4.0.0"
      }
    }
```